# Elliptic Curves Without Geometry

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

Unfortunately geometry terrifies me, so I was hoping to understand the basic theory of elliptic curves algebraically (via their function fields). Let F be a transcendence degree 1 extension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that F has genus 1.

(i) What are the $\mathbb{Q}$-points (e.g. in terms of the DVR's contained in F)?

(ii) What is the meaning of the point at infinity?

(iii) What is the meaning of coordinate change between the standard charts of P$^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$)?

I would be especially interested in descriptions which could be made effective.  In other words, explanations which use the word 'choose' as frequently as possible :)  But **any** guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The point at infinity can be seen as the slope of the asymptote of the curve.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Dear Thomas, If the curve is tangent to the point at infinty (as is the case for a parabola , say $y = x^2$, or a standard Weierstrass equation $y^2 = f(x)$ for an elliptic curve), then you don't really see an aysymptote when you plot the curve in affine space.  Regards,

Comment: Yeah, its less about asymptotes than it is about the limit of the slope. But asymptote is a more "natural" idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A $\mathbb Q$-point corresponds to a DVR whose residue field equals $\mathbb Q$.
The function field can't tell the point at infinity from any other point; the notion of "point a infinity" is not intrinsic, but is defined relative to the embedding of the curve into $\mathbb P^2$ (and a choice of coords. on $\mathbb P^2$, so that we know what the line at infinity is in $\mathbb P^2$.

The coordinate changes don't have any meaning in terms of the function field;
at best they manifest as different choices of generators.

E.g. if $E$ is given by $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$,
then its function field $F$ equals $\mathbb Q(x)[y]/(y^2 - x^3 -ax - b ).$

If we were to change coords., say write $x= X/Z, y  = Y/Z$ in terms of homo.
coords, and then change to $u = X/Y = x/y, v = Z/Y = 1/y,$ 
so that the equation for our curve becomes $v = u^3 + a u v^2 + bv^3,$
then we would obtain the alternative expression  $F = \mathbb Q(v)[u]/
(u^3 +a uv^2 + b v^3 - v ),$ where $u = x/y,$ and $v = 1/y$.

---

A side remark: it's pretty hopeless to get very far in the theory of elliptic curves without thinking geometrically.  Try using your grounding in algebra as a tool and starting point for developing more geomeric intuition.  Algebraic geometry lends itself very well to this approach.

Comment: Matt, in the case of function fields, can't we understand coordinate choice as fixing a particular subring of $F$ whose fraction field is $F$. Changing coordinates would then by applying an automorphism of $F$ which carries generators over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of one ring choice to another. For example, consider $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_p)$. The two standard coordinate charts correspond to $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ and $\mathbb{F}_p[t^{-1}]$. In the first chart, the only valuation not arising from a prime of $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ is $v_{t^{-1}}$. The change of coordinates $t\mapsto t^{-1}$

Comment: then sends one chart $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ to the other chart $\mathbb{F}_p[t^{-1}]$. It also replaces the missing valuation $v_{t^{-1}}$ with the valuation $v_t$. Is there some way to make sense of this in a more general context?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Dear Alex, You're right, a choice of affine coordinates induces a choice of affine open in $E$, and hence an affine ring $A$ of which $F$ is the fraction field.  Different affine patches in $\mathbb P^2$ then induce different $A$'s.  As you say, it is also easy to tell which discrete valuations correspond to points lying in the affine curve corresponding to $A$ and which don't (i.e. lie at infinity instead).  On the other hand, once one is doing to much of this sort of thing, I don't see how it's much different to simply doing geometry.    Regards,

Comment: Thank you both for your input. @MattE I'll do my best to follow your advice.  Unfortunately I was trying to use this algebraic approach to grow comfortable working with projective space, as despite the various ways I've heard it motivated (e.g. as a compactification,  the n=1 case over $\mathbb{C}$, improved intersection theory) I just don't feel comfortable working with it.   I will ask a separate question about this.